# React testing library - TypeError: expect(...).toHaveTextContent is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

I'm following a simple tutorial to learn react testing library.

I have a simple component like:

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';

const TestElements = () => {
  const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0)

  return(
    <>
      <h1 data-testid="counter" >{ counter }</h1>
      <button data-testid="button-up" onClick={() => setCounter(counter + 1)}>Up</button>
      <button data-testid="button-down" onClick={() => setCounter(counter - 1)}>Down</button>
    </>
  )
}

export default TestElements
```

And a test file like:

```
import React from 'react';
import {render, cleanup} from '@testing-library/react'
import TestElements from './TestElements';

afterEach(cleanup);

test('should equal to 0', () => {
    const { getByTestId } = render(<TestElements />)
    expect(getByTestId('counter')).toHaveTextContent(0)
});
```

But if I run the test, I'm getting the following error:

```
TypeError: expect(...).toHaveTextContent is not a function
```

I'm using create-react-app and the `package.json` shows:

```
"@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
```

Do I need to add jest as well?

Comment: Have you imported Jest DOM's extend-expect anywhere? See https://testing-library.com/docs/ecosystem-jest-dom

Comment: `"@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",` is included when you use create-react-app

Comment: The dependency is included, and should be loaded in `src/setupTests.js` (assuming you're using the default template). But what changes have you made, is this reproducible in a brand new CRA app? What's the tutorial?

Comment: Its this tutorial so I didn't create the create-react-app but clones the app from the tutorial - https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/8-simple-steps-to-start-testing-react-apps-using-react-testing-library-and-jest/

Comment: As a simple check, does adding the right import to your test code fix it? It works fine in the example I put together with CRA4 in my own tutorial (https://blog.jonrshar.pe/2020/Nov/22/js-tdd-e2e.html), but the repo lacks the setupTests file.

Comment: what do you mean right import ?

Comment: See my first comment.

Comment: yes I tried that but doesn't work

Comment: OK so Ive created my own app with create-react-app and it works haha so much for the tutorial

Comment: I vaguely recall you might have had to import `@testing-library/jest-dom/extend-expect` at one point, maybe that tutorial uses an older version where that would work. Or you're welcome to give mine a go!

Comment: See [react-testing-library issue 379](https://github.com/testing-library/react-testing-library/issues/379)

Answer (score 59, accepted):

I think you're following [this freeCodeCamp tutorial](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/8-simple-steps-to-start-testing-react-apps-using-react-testing-library-and-jest/) you mentioned in your other question.

To solve your issue, you need to add the custom jest matchers from jest-dom by importing `"@testing-library/jest-dom/extend-expect"` in your test file. It is also mentioned in React Testing Library's [full example](https://testing-library.com/docs/react-testing-library/example-intro/).

```js
import React from 'react';
import {render, cleanup} from '@testing-library/react';
import '@testing-library/jest-dom/extend-expect';

import TestElements from './TestElements';

afterEach(cleanup);
...
```

Edit: I've just read the comments under your question and it seems @jonrsharpe has already mentioned that you need to import `extend-expect` but I'll leave this answer here.

Comment: I was stuck, but in the case of a mono repo where I knew I wrote tests using `toHaveFocus` in another area I couldn't get why the same assertions weren't available in another lib. From this answer I finally figured out I had to add a per-lib `jest-setup.ts (or .js)` with `import '@testing-library/jest-dom';` and
`import '@testing-library/jest-dom/extend-expect';`. And that fixed my nx lib testing issue.

Comment: ^ and then I had to add to `jest-config.ts`: `setupFilesAfterEnv: ['<rootDir>/jest-setup.ts'],`

Answer (score 11):

I'd recommend having a *setupTests.js* file that contains:

```
import "@testing-library/jest-dom";
```

as suggested here: https://create-react-app.dev/docs/running-tests#react-testing-library